# How to monitor AWS Billing Credits?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-billing

Because of business needs, I now need to monitor the service deduction amount of AWS. When the service deduction amount is less than $5000, I will give an alarm to relevant management personnel. Is there a way to realize this? I checked the documentation of AWS cost Explorer API on the official website, but I didn't see the API related to the service deduction amount.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Budgets to create an alert where your credits are at a certain threshold. You can use the advance filters to alert only on credits

[image]

You can also check https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/how-to-set-aws-budget-when-paying-with-aws-credits/

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I recommend AWS cloud watch and Grafana dashboard.

https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/139

Comment: Cloudwatch doesn't track credits usage metrics